# How to get hash of filtered collections in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there a way to get the Hash on  a filtered Collection?

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dbHash/#dbcmd.dbHash

```
db.runCommand ( { dbHash: 1, collections: [ 'persons' ] } )
```

According to the docs I can get the hash of a Collection. But I would like to
get only the hash of the `persons.age >= 18` and I don't see how to do it.

Just to give more context:

I need to keep two DBs synced and not all the data exist in both DBs because the information is separated according to some business logic.